# Find the anagram pairs of from 2 lists and create a list of tuples of the anagrams

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, anagram

say I have two lists

`list_1 = [ 'Tar', 'Arc', 'Elbow', 'State', 'Cider', 'Dusty', 'Night', 'Inch', 'Brag', 'Cat', 'Bored', 'Save', 'Angel','bla', 'Stressed', 'Dormitory', 'School master','Awesoame', 'Conversation', 'Listen', 'Astronomer', 'The eyes', 'A gentleman', 'Funeral', 'The Morse Code', 'Eleven plus two', 'Slot machines', 'Fourth of July', 'Jim Morrison', 'Damon Albarn', 'George Bush', 'Clint Eastwood', 'Ronald Reagan', 'Elvis', 'Madonna Louise Ciccone', 'Bart', 'Paris', 'San Diego', 'Denver', 'Las Vegas', 'Statue of Liberty']`

and

`list_B = ['Cried', 'He bugs Gore', 'They see', 'Lives', 'Joyful Fourth', 'The classroom', 'Diagnose', 'Silent', 'Taste', 'Car', 'Act', 'Nerved', 'Thing', 'A darn long era', 'Brat', 'Twelve plus one', 'Elegant man', 'Below', 'Robed', 'Study', 'Voices rant on', 'Chin', 'Here come dots', 'Real fun', 'Pairs', 'Desserts', 'Moon starer', 'Dan Abnormal', 'Old West action', 'Built to stay free', 'One cool dance musician', 'Dirty room', 'Grab', 'Salvages', 'Cash lost in me', "Mr. Mojo Risin'", 'Glean', 'Rat', 'Vase']`

What I am looking for is to find the anagram pairs of list_A in list_B. Create a list of tuples of the anagrams.
For one list I can do the following and generate the list of tuples, however, for two lists I need some assistance. Thanks in advance for the help!

What I have tried for one list,

```
from collections import defaultdict

anagrams = defaultdict(list)
for w in list_A:
    anagrams[tuple(sorted(w))].append(w)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested for loop, outer for the first list, inner for the second (also, use `str.lower` to make it case-insensitive):

```
anagram_pairs = [] #  (w_1 from list_A, w_2 from list_B)

for w_1 in list_A:
    for w_2 in list_B:
        if sorted(w_1.lower()) == sorted(w_2.lower()):
            anagram_pairs.append((w_1, w_2))

print(anagram_pairs)
```

Output:

```
[('Tar', 'Rat'), ('Arc', 'Car'), ('Elbow', 'Below'), ('State', 'Taste'), ('Cider', 'Cried'), ('Dusty', 'Study'), ('Night', 'Thing'), ('Inch', 'Chin'), ('Brag', 'Grab'), ('Cat', 'Act'), ('Bored', 'Robed'), ('Save', 'Vase'), ('Angel', 'Glean'), ('Stressed', 'Desserts'), ('School master', 'The classroom'), ('Listen', 'Silent'), ('The eyes', 'They see'), ('A gentleman', 'Elegant man'), ('The Morse Code', 'Here come dots'), ('Eleven plus two', 'Twelve plus one'), ('Damon Albarn', 'Dan Abnormal'), ('Elvis', 'Lives'), ('Bart', 'Brat'), ('Paris', 'Pairs'), ('Denver', 'Nerved')]
```

Comment: Thanks, both of the solutions worked like a charm! how can make it computationally effective What if the lists are really large?

Comment: @user1017373 to make it computationally efficient, use Ajax or Andrej's approach, which are `O(M+N)` instead of this one which is `O(M*N)`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The reason I didn't want to use one shared dictionary was because I thought words in one list could possibly have anagrams in that same list (or multiple anagrams in the other list), e.g. if a word in `list_A` had an anagram in `list_A` and another in `list_B`, then the entry in the dictionary will have three values, so to guarantee tuples (one from A, one from B), I used this approach. But sure, if the input is guaranteed to be the way it is in the question, then @AndrejKesely's and @Ajax1234's approaches are faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are quite close with your current attempt. All you need to do is repeat the same process on `list_B`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
anagrams = defaultdict(list)
list_A = [ 'Tar', 'Arc', 'Elbow', 'State', 'Cider', 'Dusty', 'Night', 'Inch', 'Brag', 'Cat', 'Bored', 'Save', 'Angel','bla', 'Stressed', 'Dormitory', 'School master','Awesoame', 'Conversation', 'Listen', 'Astronomer', 'The eyes', 'A gentleman', 'Funeral', 'The Morse Code', 'Eleven plus two', 'Slot machines', 'Fourth of July', 'Jim Morrison', 'Damon Albarn', 'George Bush', 'Clint Eastwood', 'Ronald Reagan', 'Elvis', 'Madonna Louise Ciccone', 'Bart', 'Paris', 'San Diego', 'Denver', 'Las Vegas', 'Statue of Liberty']
list_B = ['Cried', 'He bugs Gore', 'They see', 'Lives', 'Joyful Fourth', 'The classroom', 'Diagnose', 'Silent', 'Taste', 'Car', 'Act', 'Nerved', 'Thing', 'A darn long era', 'Brat', 'Twelve plus one', 'Elegant man', 'Below', 'Robed', 'Study', 'Voices rant on', 'Chin', 'Here come dots', 'Real fun', 'Pairs', 'Desserts', 'Moon starer', 'Dan Abnormal', 'Old West action', 'Built to stay free', 'One cool dance musician', 'Dirty room', 'Grab', 'Salvages', 'Cash lost in me', "Mr. Mojo Risin'", 'Glean', 'Rat', 'Vase']
for w in list_A:
   anagrams[tuple(sorted(w))].append(w)

for w in list_B:
   anagrams[tuple(sorted(w))].append(w)

result = [b for b in anagrams.values() if len(b) > 1]
```

Output:

```
[['Cider', 'Cried'], ['The eyes', 'They see'], ['Damon Albarn', 'Dan Abnormal'], ['Bart', 'Brat'], ['Paris', 'Pairs']]
```

Comment: `sorted(w.lower())` will find case-insensitive anagrams

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using dictionary:

```py
out = {}
for word in list_A:
    out.setdefault(tuple(sorted(word.lower())), []).append(word)

for word in list_B:
    word_s = tuple(sorted(word.lower()))
    if word_s in out:
        out[word_s].append(word)

print(list(tuple(v) for v in out.values() if len(v) > 1))
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ("Tar", "Rat"),
    ("Arc", "Car"),
    ("Elbow", "Below"),
    ("State", "Taste"),
    ("Cider", "Cried"),
    ("Dusty", "Study"),
    ("Night", "Thing"),
    ("Inch", "Chin"),
    ("Brag", "Grab"),
    ("Cat", "Act"),
    ("Bored", "Robed"),
    ("Save", "Vase"),
    ("Angel", "Glean"),
    ("Stressed", "Desserts"),
    ("School master", "The classroom"),
    ("Listen", "Silent"),
    ("The eyes", "They see"),
    ("A gentleman", "Elegant man"),
    ("The Morse Code", "Here come dots"),
    ("Eleven plus two", "Twelve plus one"),
    ("Damon Albarn", "Dan Abnormal"),
    ("Elvis", "Lives"),
    ("Bart", "Brat"),
    ("Paris", "Pairs"),
    ("Denver", "Nerved"),
]
```